# conversion from fixdt to uint32 in Simulink and Matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink, type-conversion, fixed-point

I am having a kind of behavior with Simulink and Matlab, that I would be delighted if anyone could help me understand, here what it is about :

I want to convert from fixed-point to integer data type, can any one help me understand the difference between these two behaviour between Matlab and Simulink ?

### In Matlab

> > a = fi(1000,0,32,0.01,0);
> >
> > b = uint32(a);
> >
> > The value of b is b = 1000.

### In Simulink

[image: Example in SImulink]

The problem is related to the Rounding method (Zero) in the DataTypeConversion block, with other methods i get the same result as Matlab (I am constrained to use Zero rounding method).

#### What I was expecting with the Simulink example :

I expected to not to loose precision, even with the 'Zero' rounding method, since the data typing of the Constant block is Unsigned, Slope = 0.01 and Bias =0 .

Someone please can explain why I get this precision lose.

Thank you.